# Changing background URL of a:before with CSS/SASS and color of text on focus.

Tags: html, css, sass, frontend

I need to change the background URL of an SVG icon when focused on a link.

This is the HTML:

```
<a class="foo" href="google.com">
    <span>Help</span>
</a>
```

This is the SASS I've done so far to no avail:

```
.foo {
    &:before {
        background: url("#{$active}") center center no-repeat;
    }

   [data-whatintent='keyboard'] &:focus {
        background-color: transparent; // Currently purple, make it transparent
         color: purple; // Currently white, make it purple
         &:before {
             background: url("#{$focus}") center center no-repeat;
         }
         span {
             background-color: purple;
             color: white;
         }
    }
}
```

How can I make it so that onFocus I change the background color of the `span` to purple, the text of the `span` white and the change the url of the background on &:before? What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: What this `[data-whatintent=‘keyboard’]` does and where is that applied in your html?

Comment: Its a library called [what-input](https://github.com/ten1seven/what-input) @muecas

Comment: And that data attribute is applied to which element? To `a.foo`?

Comment: Yes, to actionable items such as `a.foo` @muecas

Comment: Ok, i proposed a solution, please test it so i can further assist you to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming what you mentioned in your comment (`a.foo` gets the data attribute `[data-whatintent="keyboard"]`), you should modify your `scss` code a bit:

```
.foo {
    &:before {
        background: url("#{$active}") center center no-repeat;
    }

   &[data-whatintent='keyboard']:focus { // Modified line
       background-color: transparent;
       color: purple;
       &:before {
           background: url("#{$focus}") center center no-repeat;
       }
       span {
           background-color: purple;
           color: white;
       }
    }
}
```

In your code `[data-whatintent='keyboard'] &:focus` compiled to `[data-whatintent='keyboard'] .foo:focus` so the selector applied to `.foo:focus` contained by `[data-whatintent='keyboard']`. If, like you mentioned in your comments, is `.foo` the element that gets the data attribute, the code i proposed should work.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Actually this won't work. I apologize, I misspoke. The data attribute is set on the document <html>. I found that there is no way around it because of all the conflicting specificity. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: So, your code should work if the data attribute is not set thru JavaScript. What conflict is that? Maybe just specifying the data attribute and not its value will work.